# How to pass a weak reference to the activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to implement a main handler for an android class.
How do I instantiate MyHandler object with the weak reference of the activity?

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity {
    class MyHandler(var mActivityRef: WeakReference<MainActivity>): Handler(){
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
            var activity: MainActivity? = mActivityRef.get()// get actual object from weak reference

            if(activity != null) {
                if (msg?.what == 0) {
                //...some logic
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be done like this:
`val myHandler = MyHandler(WeakReference(this))`
where `this` is an instance of your activity

Comment: It complains like this: Property getter or setter expected

Comment: Could you please post a code, that you use to instantiate a handler? Because I can't reproduce such a message about getter or setter expected.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I mistakenly used "var" instead of "val".
It worked. I don't understand why this made difference though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's better to directly pass the `Activity` instance in the constructor and just do

```
this.weaActivity = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(activityRef);
```

Classes outside of `MyHandler` do not need to know that the `Activity` is saved into a `Reference`. This is an implementation detail relevant only to `MyHandler`

Comment: This solution works too. 
You mean typecasting WeakReference to the activity, right?

Comment: He means pass a strong reference then wrap it up in a weak reference on the other side. There's little need in not just boxing the reference outside of the handler as the handler is started by the activity that clearly existed when it started.

Comment: @PeterHwang well the `WeakReference` must be typecasted for the `Activity`. The point was to initialize the `WeakReference` inside the constructor. @Tatarize explained that quite well.